# Is there a way to request iMessage history from Apple?

Tags: apple-id, messages, history

Recently there was a famous case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBI%E2%80%93Apple_encryption_dispute

I was wondering if a regular citizen *(US or non-US based)* can apply to Apple and **request all the iMessage history** since the creation of my AppleID?

*(random thought: I should read T&C and privacy policy to learn who actually owns the right to my own messages)*

Alternatively - is there a service that would retrieve all the history without any involvement from Apple?

---

Caveats:

- I've been changing devices so not sure if that would work: [How can I locate an iMessage from 1-2 months ago? Possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216333/how-can-i-locate-an-imessage-from-1-2-months-ago-possible)
- I'd would the material to be admissible in the court

Comment: Check out the accepted answer from [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/216356/88313).  If it helps you then I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: That's the question I referenced in my question and apparently the messages span only back to February - http://i.imgur.com/PqeZZEq.png - time when I reinstalled me OS...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that link somehow.

Comment: Of course you can request it -- how could you be prevented from doing so? Just write a letter to Apple. They won't _comply_ with your request, of course.

Comment: @MikeScott Write a letter. Of course. Which department. Which legal paragraph to quote. If I lawyer-up they may actually may want to comply... Any suggestions here?

Comment: @MichalStefanow I just saw [this page](http://www.iphonerecovery.com/recover-deleted-imessages-from-iphone-ipad.html) while looking for something else and I remembered you had a question about it.  I don't know if it will work for you or not.  If it does, post back here and I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you store your iMessage data on iCloud (New feature introduced iOS 11.3), Apple does not directly store your iMessage data. There may be instances of iMessage data in iCloud Backup. This data can be extracted by various recovery programs, but not "requested" from Apple.

Even if you do store it on iCloud it is encrypted is not accessible in the fashion you are requesting it.

You can however [request a copy of all the data Apple has](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/get-a-copy-of-your-apple-account-data/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Apple doesn't store your iMessage history. Case in point I am missing loads of iMessages on my Mac after a clean install that are present on my iPhone. You would need to back it up yourself.